# OpenCV Android Create New Image Using the Edges of the Largest Contour

Tags: android, opencv, edge-detection

I am able to detect the largest square/rectangle (in green) in an image. However, I want to convert the largest square/rectangle detected in the image into a new image (to be stored in a new Mat).

Here's the return image of this function that has the largest rectangle/square on it: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9308/nn4w.png

Here is my code so far:

```
private Mat findLargestRectangle(Mat original_image) {
    Mat imgSource = original_image;

    //convert the image to black and white
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
    Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 50, 50);

    //apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    //find the contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double maxArea = -1;
    int maxAreaIdx = -1;
    MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
    Mat largest_contour = contours.get(0);
    List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
        temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
        double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
        //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
        if (contourarea > maxArea) {
            //check if this contour is a square
            MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
            int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.05, true);
            if (approxCurve.total() == 4) {
                maxArea = contourarea;
                maxAreaIdx = idx;
                largest_contours.add(temp_contour);
                largest_contour = temp_contour;
            }
        }
    }
    MatOfPoint temp_largest = largest_contours.get(largest_contours.size()-1);
    largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    largest_contours.add(temp_largest);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
    Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);

    //create the new image here using the largest detected square

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Largest Contour: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return imgSource;
}
```

The variable **largest_contours** is a list of MatOfPoint but only contains the largest contour, also stored in **largest_contour** variable. How can I possible make a new image from the largest contour?

I am using OpenCV in Android and there are few tutorials for detecting images but not exactly on how to use Imgproc.warpPerspective()

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "make a new image"? What does this "new image" contain?

Comment: Hello @Aurelius, this is what I was trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512234/android-opencv-find-largest-square-or-rectangle. I posted this few weeks ago and now that I can detect the largest square contour in the image, I want to crop that image and create a new one.

Comment: I used this code successfully to find out the largest rectangle. I also found out a way to save the resulting image. The resulting image comes in black and white. How can I prevent that? I want it to be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to find the corners of this contour. You can use [extreme points](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/contours-3-extraction.html) approach.

You should simply find out the point having minimum x and minimum y (this is your topleft), minimum x maximum y (this is your bottom left), and so on.

In C++, there is a library named *algoritm* which has min/max methods. For instance [min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) will help you to find the point having minimum x or y. Don't forget to include  header.

After having your 4 points, you can use perspective transform.

First input your points to [this method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform). The destination should be

```
Point2f dest[4] = {(0,0),(image.width,0),(0,image.height),(image.height,image.width)}
```

for your case. The matrix (M) you obtain from this method will transform your points to destination using [another method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective).

Good luck.

Edit: On the second thought; since your contour is not a parallelogram, you have your extreme points as min x = bottomleft, min y = topleft, and so on. Then it is easier to find the minimum element.

Comment: Hello Bacci, thanks for the response. Thanks for the algorithm for determining the extreme points. The quadrilateral can be a parallelogram though as the image comes from a mobile camera. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Canberk Baci, here's my progress so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637730/android-opencv-getperspectivetransform-and-warpperspective You're a big help in this project. thanks!

Comment: I don't think extreme approach will work for the rectangle rotated by an angle(sides of which are not parallel to the coordinate axis).

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way of using drawContour on a new Mat. [This document will help you.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

Correct way would be

```
    Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    ...

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
    Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, contours, maxAreaIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, that did help a lot of processing as I do not need the largest_contour array list. But I still badly need to crop the largest contour and create a new image from it. Thanks again!