# How to straight an image by selecting four points in an Image?

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to straight an image by selecting four points in the image using *getPerspectiveTransform()* method of opencv in java. I know it can be done using with opencv in python:
[getPerspectiveTransform](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html). If anyone used this to achieve image straightening ..please help.

[image]

Comment: take a look at http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is perspective transformation which can be used to achieve quad to quad conversion. In **OpenCV**, there are mainly two methods to achieve getPerspectiveTransformation() and warpPerspective() method.

Here is a sample code to achieve Image Straightening:

**First get four quadrilinear points in source image**

```
Mat srcImage = Imgcodecs.imread("input.png");
Mat destImage = new Mat(500, 700, srcImage.type());
Mat src = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2), new Point(x3, y3), new Point(x4, y4));
Mat dst = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point(0, 0), new Point(destImage.width() - 1, 0), new Point(destImage.width() - 1, destImage.height() - 1), new Point(0, destImage.height() - 1));
```

**Getting transformation metrix**

```
Mat transform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst);
Imgproc.warpPerspective(srcImage, destImage, transform, destImage.size());
```

you will get transformed straighten image.

I have tested this code on this image.
[image: input.png]

and The resulted image is
[image: output.png]

Comment: how to get x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4 ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Mat mat=Highgui.imread("inputImage.jpg");
Mat src_mat=new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
Mat dst_mat=new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

// Keypoint location on source image
src_mat.put(0,0,407.0,74.0,1606.0,74.0,420.0,2589.0,1698.0,2589.0);
// Desired keypoint location after straigting
dst_mat.put(0,0,0.0,0.0,1600.0,0.0, 0.0,2500.0,1600.0,2500.0);
Mat perspectiveTransform=Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(src_mat, dst_mat);

Mat dst=mat.clone();

Imgproc.warpPerspective(mat, dst, perspectiveTransform, new Size(1600,2500));
Highgui.imwrite("resultImage.jpg", dst);
```

Original thread:
[Android OpenCV getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637730/android-opencv-getperspectivetransform-and-warpperspective)